# A friend to your legs

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Have me whole, I’m a friend to your legs
>   Remove one letter, I’m a friend to your head
>   Remove once more, I become ethereal
>   Remove one more time, I can’t be seen but felt

Who am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are a

> chair

Because:

1. > A chair enables you to sit to give rest to your legs
2. > Remove c -> Hair keeps your head warm
3. > Remove h -> Air is quite ethereal
4. > Remove a -> IR (infrared) can't be seen but can be felt.

edit:
Should've reloaded to see Stiv's same answer, although a slight difference in reasoning. Quite astonishing to see similar layout.

Comment: I personally think your answer fits the fourth clue better than Stiv's

Comment: @AHKieran Personally, I do too! Both last lines technically fit, but I imagine this might be the one the OP intended...

Comment: Sorry, @Stiv, but you are right :) Credits for a great answer though!

Comment: You *can* feel the fourth thing.

Comment: There are rot13(pbbxref gung urng sbbq hfvat vasenerq enqvngvba)

Comment: Yeah "IR" is a really bad solution/hint IMO (assuming it was the authors intention).  Infrared radiation is absorbed by the body, and heats you up.  Most of the radiative heat you feel is in the IR spectrum AFAIK.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you are a:

> **CHAIR**

*Have me whole, I’m a friend to your legs*

> A **CHAIR** is 'a friend to your legs' in that it enables them to rest when you sit on one...

*Remove one letter, I’m a friend to your head*

> Remove the C --> **HAIR** - 'a friend to your head' in that hair keeps your head warm and protects it from the sun.

*Remove once more, I become ethereal*

> Remove the H --> **AIR** - one of the meanings of 'ethereal' is 'light and airy'. What can be more so than air itself?!

*Remove one more time, I can’t be felt or seen*

> Remove the R --> **AI**, or *Artificial Intelligence* - something which 'can't be felt or seen'.

Comment: It could have been: "Have me whole, I’m a friend to your legs; Remove one letter, I’m a friend to your head; Remove once more, I'm a friend to your lungs, Remove one more time, I'm a friend to your computer"

Comment: @Avi That's really neat!

Answer (score 2):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but this one also fits, to me:

> **Boots**

because

> **High boots go up to your legs and protect from muck and cold**

remove a letter to get

> **Boos, which is a brand name for cutting blocks, which in medieval times were associated with decapitation**

one more letter becomes

> **Boo! An exclamation uttered by ghosts, traditionally, which are ethereal**

And finally one last letter brings us to

> **BO, a frequent abbreviation for Body Odor; never felt or seen but only smelled!**

Comment: Oh yes decapitation, the greatest friend of heads all around!

Comment: @theonlygusti the chopping block knows the companionship of a great many heads!